# NFS root, mount speed

Tags: boot, nfs, root

I'm wondering what can I do to speed up booting from NFS server (nfs root).

I'm using Arch and there are no problem in booting over network, but still, it needs ~2 minutes to start booting and then it boots in 3 seconds or so.

I think that there might be some problems in NFS or DHCP server, but I'm not sure.

If you are using similar way of booting, how fast is it for you?

UPDATE:

It looks like this slow boot appears only with using `ip=dhcp` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`, so that might me my DHCP server. I'm not sure why is it so, as for other devices, DHCP server much faster than 2 minutes.

Comment: \Try setting static IP and see if it works. If it does then yea, its DHCP being slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've realized what was the problem to my case, but I never posted it here.

Anyways, it was because my switch (cisco 2960) had strange rules for spanning tree. I had to turn on feature called FastPort to speed it up to only few seconds.

Comment: The symptom there is that you see the port indicator on the Cisco switch go yellow and stay that way for the better part of a minute. If you set `spanning-tree portfast`, the port should go green immediately when a device is attached. Just be careful if you attach a switch to a port configured for portfast. Without that, the 2960 goes through a spanning tree negotiation phase every time you plug in a device to avoid loops if you plug in other switches downstream.

Comment: @bobstro you are right, I wish I had you once this problem was bothering me (for few days)

Comment: In general, always check to make sure those port lights are green on the Cisco before you start ripping other stuff apart. Until the link layer is up, nothing's going to work.